# retain in pipe character in text file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed, sh

I have a pipe delimited file with 2 columns:

```
GTB_NIASNA_S1|Select right('000000000000000' **"\|"**| CIS_ID,15) as CISNO,g.* from trgisl.GTB_NIASNA g where \$CONDITIONS AND g.CIS_ID <> '000000000000000' and g.CIS_ID is not null
```

I am trying to read this file using a script:

> IFS="|" sed 1,3d /home/ndeshpande/tables_gtb.txt|while read f1 f2 do
>   echo $f2 done

However when it prints the value it takes of the pipe in the select query:

> Select right('000000000000000' **" "**  CIS_ID,15) as CISNO,g.* from
>   trgisl.GTB_NIASNA g where $CONDITIONS AND g.CIS_ID <>
>   '000000000000000' and g.CIS_ID is not null

I tried putting all the escape characters but it didn't work. Wonder if there is anyway to retain the pipes in select query

Comment: Are you just trying to skip the first column?  `cut` may be more useful.  `cat tables_gtb.txt | cut -d\| -f2-`

Comment: No I want to retain the pipes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure someone had posted before and that was something i was looking for. The IFS that I am using is not at correct place. I fixed my code accordingly:

```
sed 1,3d /home/ndeshpande/tables_gtb.txt|while IFS="|" read f1 f2
do
echo $f2
done
```

Instead of putting IFS before I am using it in the while and that worked for me.